# vba - adding sub-directories to a dynamic array

Tags: vba

I am making a macro that adds sub-directories to an array. The number of sub-directories is unspecified, so I reDim the array to the size of the array counter each time through. When I try to set the array value at index value, "count", I get: compile error: expected array.

I tried to keep my code as simple as possible, and to me it seems like it should work, but it obviously doesn't. Would someone mind pointing out where I muddled it up?

```
'DEFINE PATH AND SUBDIRECTORY DIR
Path = "C:\Users\MyComp\Documents\test\folders\" 
Dim SubDir
SubDir = Dir(Path, vbDirectory)



'CREATE ARRAY AND COUNTER
Dim folderindex As Long 
Dim count As Integer
count = 0



'ADD SUBDIRECTORY PATHNAMES TO ARRAY
Do Until SubDir = ""   
    folderindex(count) = Path & SubDir
    count = count + 1
    ReDim Preserve folderindex(count)
SubDir = Dir()   
Loop



End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: In addition to answers below, it is also good practice to `Dim` everything in the beginning, rather than `Dim`-ing as you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare variable which becomes an array you need to use parenthesis in this way:

```
Dim folderindex() As String
```

**Important!!** Moreover, you need to declare variable `As String` (type) as you are going to keep text inside, not numbers.

Comment: thanks, now trying to figure out if it is actually adding to array, and looping through

Comment: well, now I'm onto another problem, but that got me past the first hump thanks KazJaw

Comment: I did MsgBox folderindex(0) to see if anything was in the array, but nothing is. Any idea why that is?

Comment: what do you want to achieve- get subfolders of given folder?